# Preferred library and/or method of converting CMYK to RGB

Tags: image, scripting, imagemagick, cmyk

Each month I get new CMYK and RGB images that shall be used on the web.

I had a script using a patched up ImageMagick doing this, but it got deleted. So I need to do it again, but it was hard last time.

How do you *easily* and quickly convert CMYK image files to RGB?

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
convert CMYK.tiff -profile "RGB.icc" RGB.tiff
```

Answer (score 1):

> convert cmyk_image.jpg -colorspace
>   rgb rgb_image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The answer of g.b.1981 basically is correct (+1), but...

To make it work reliable, I found I had to add `-type truecolor` to the commandline:

```
convert cmyk.jpg -colorspace rgb -type truecolor rgb.jpg
```